# Why app icon cannot be removed in itunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I need to update a new app icon for a app store rejected app, But I am unable to remove the app Icon in the itunes connect, Can any one help me to remove and update new icon.[image]

I tried to remove the icon by the minus button, after that there is no option to add new icon
[image]

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: amod i am using safari browser

Comment: solution provided by Dheeraj should work. Do you have latest version of Safari installed? Try to clear cache / restart... Try to view it in different browser other than safari. If issue still persist open a ticket with apple.

Comment: Yes tried in both safari and chrome still same problem

Answer (score 1):

Go to **My apps** -> **Prepare for submission** Hover over mouse over your app icon you will be able to see remove icon, see below screen shot:

[image]

For **Developer Rejected**

If you have already removed app icon and not able to see option to add new so SAVE it first and then click on some another tab like : **App Information** and **Pricing and availability** and click back to developer rejected. you will be able to  see option like below screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Dheeraj yes I tried this too but cant remove , when i click the minus button the app icon removed but there is no option to add new app icon.

Comment: dheraj now i added some addition screenshots after trying u r idea.

Comment: It might be bug from apple's site but try to make your application state to Prepare for submission from Rejected and try

Comment: Did you save your changes after removing the app icon? I find I sometimes need to save so the page and app status refreshes

Comment: TomyBs yes i changed after removing but still the icon was fixed cannot change.

Comment: "Arun" i hope my edited answer will work for you. :)

Comment: Dheeraj i will tryy.

Comment: Dheeraj again i tried but unable to submit the new icon

Comment: I'm trying to remove IOS App version But, I mouse hover It's not showing any delete option like yours. I'm using safari browser for performing operation. anyone know how to do this. My question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986821/is-it-possible-to-change-apple-store-connect-app-version-name?noredirect=1#comment114904265_64986821.